# Find the largest positive number in my given data?

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, numeric-data

Can someone show me a way to find the largest positive number using awk,sed or some sort of unix shell program? I'm using Linux RHEL with KSH. The input may have 8 columns worth of data with N/A as one of the possible values.

```
SAMPLE INPUT

1252.2          1251.8          N/A             N/A 
-31.9           -33.2           N/A             N/A 
-1172.4         -1174.4         N/A             N/A 
-6.5            -6.4            N/A             N/A 
-.3             -.3             N/A             N/A 
1351.8          1351.8          N/A             N/A 
38.3            38.0            N/A             N/A 
-21.6           -21.9           N/A             N/A 
-4.7            -4.5            N/A             N/A 
-5.0            -2.9            N/A             N/A 
3.1             3.3             N/A             N/A 
-20.1           -20.3           N/A             N/A 
-199.1          -199.3          N/A             N/A 
346.5           346.7           N/A             N/A 
-.8             -.4             N/A             N/A 
14.8            14.7            N/A             N/A 
8.4             8.4             N/A             N/A 
-18.2           -18.2           N/A             N/A 
-43.7           -43.6           N/A             N/A
```

Desired output

```
Largest number is 1351.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bash-style solution using `tr`, `sort` and `head`

```
echo $(< file) | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -rn | head -1
```

- `echo $(< file)` reads the file and echoes the result. But as we don't have quotes around it (`echo "$(< file)"` does the same as `cat file`) the content is one long string with newlines removed and whitespace squeezed
- `| tr ' ' '\n'` pipes the result through `tr` replacing each space character with  a newline
- `| sort -rn` pipes the result to `sort`, sorting all lines in reversed (-r) numeric (-n) order (largest number first)
- `| head -1` pipes the result to `head` to output the first line

Comment: replacing head -1 with tail -1 will give the smallest. Nice. This is exactly what i want.

Comment: Yes. Or you can sort with `sort -n` to get the smallest :)

Comment: I don't see the point of the `echo $(<file)`, starting the pipeline with a `<file tr -s ' ' '\n'` should suffice

Comment: @iruvar Correct.

Comment: How about `tr ' ' '\n' < file | sort -rn | head -1`

Comment: @CharlesGreen Yeah, I like that too.

Answer (score 3):

With Awk, forcing numeric evaluation of the `N/A` entries:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) max = $i+0 > max ? $i : max} END{print "Largest number is " max}' data
```

Comment: Why the `$i+0` in the `max` assignment's test ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: @Cbhihe it was intended to prevent unintended lexical comparison of any non-numeric fields - but perhaps it's not necessary

Answer (score 2):

One way can be:

```
perl -lane '$_>$m and $m=$_ for @F}{print $m' sample.txt
```

Explanation:

1. `-n` option will process your input file on a per line basis.
2. `-e` option will apply the Perl code following it, to every line of input read.
3. `-a` option will split each line as it is read into individual fields and store them in an array `@F`.
4. `-l` option will make RS=ORS="\n"
5. `for @F` will loop over each field, the current field being held in `$_`.
6. We compare the current field with the maximum and in case it it more than max, update max.
7. When we are done comparing, }{ we print what is held in max.
8. The `N/A`s shall be treated as 0 in numeric context so won't affect the result, unless of course all numerics were negative to begin with.

Comment: this is working fine. Can you explain how it works ?

Comment: Done. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below method
Command

```
awk '{print $0}' o.txt | sed -r "s/\s+/\n/g"| sed '/^$/d'| sort | uniq| sed -n '/[0-9]/p'| awk 'BEGIN{sum=0;m=" "}($1 >sum){sum=$1}{m=sum}END{print m}'
```

Output

```
 awk '{print $0}' o.txt | sed -r "s/\s+/\n/g"| sed '/^$/d'| sort | uniq| sed -n '/[0-9]/p'| awk 'BEGIN{sum=0;m=" "}($1 >sum){sum=$1}{m=sum}END{print m}'
```

output

```
1351.8
```